# How to access the products array in the category page (bigcommerce handelbars stencil)

Tags: handlebars.js, bigcommerce, bigcommerce-stencil-cli

I'm working with stencil handelbars, a bigcommerce website. I'm working in the category page, and I want to have access to the products array, which is not present there. I don't know too much about handelbars helpers, and if there is some of those that would help me.
Is there a way to make the products array available in the category page?